# Nokogiri XML Parsing with Ruby Sinatra

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, sinatra, nokogiri

I'm having difficulty selecting a URL within an XML document using Nokogiri, have tried using CSS selectors which works fine apart from markup within the  child. I think this has to be due to the brackets < being written as &lt and &gt. Is there a way around this?

```
&lt;br /&gt;&lt;strong&gt;URL:&lt;/strong&gt; &lt;a href="https://url.com/"&gt;https://url.com/&lt;/a&gt;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'cgi'
CGI.unescapeHTML('&lt;br /&gt;&lt;strong&gt;URL:&lt;/strong&gt; &lt;a href="https://url.com/"&gt;https://url.com/&lt;/a&gt;')
```

gives

```
<br /><strong>URL:</strong> <a href=\"https://url.com/\">https://url.com/</a>
```

Maybe you just need to unescape your html first